# Windows 2012 R2 CA - certsrv missing templates field

Tags: certificate, windows-server-2012-r2, ssl-certificate

Has anybody come across an issue where the certificate templates field is not available in the CA menu, `http://localhost/certsrv/certrqxt.asp`?

[image: certsrv Bad]

What it should look like is:

[image: certsrv Good]

Has anybody any idea what i am missing, is there something else i need to install here?

Thanks, Kevin